# How to create a working loop for :hover actions in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I'm trying to create a  drop-right sidebar through a javascript/jquery code that modifies CSS properties of specific attributes such as display and stuff. I tried replace the current selectors with the arrays below, using for/while loops it didn't work out. Could please you help me? Thanks in advance

```
            var linha = ["#veg","#anim","#flo","#pesc","#def","#maq","#rac","#carn","#art","#bio","#cel","#text","#out","#pol","#fum","#mad","#etc1","#tran","#arm","#fin","#jur","#cons","#prop","#tes","#op","#sec","#etc2"];

            var tab = ["#Div0","#Div1","#Div2","#Div3"];



            $("#veg,#Div0,#ico0").hover(function() {
            $("#Div0").css("display","block");
            },function() {
            $("#Div0").css("display","none");
            });
              $("#veg,#Div0,#ico0").hover(function() {
            $("#veg").css("background-color","white")
            .css("color","#bada55")
            .css("border","1px","solid","#e7e7e7");
            },function() {
            $("#veg").css("background-color","initial")
            .css("color","initial");
                  $("#veg,#Div0,#ico0").hover(function() {
            $("#ico0").css("filter","grayscale(0%)");
            },function() {
            $("#ico0").css("filter","grayscale(100%)");
            });

            });
            //---------------------------------------------//
            $("#anim,#Div1,#ico1").hover(function() {
            $("#Div1").css("display","block");
            },function() {
            $("#Div1").css("display","none");
            });
              $("#anim,#Div1,#ico1").hover(function() {
            $("#anim").css("background-color","white")
            .css("color","#bada55")
            .css("border","1px","solid","#e7e7e7");
            },function() {
            $("#anim").css("background-color","initial")
            .css("color","initial");
            });
```

Comment: You should consider just adding a class to a parent div on hover and then style the children according to the state of the parent. The code above is messy and difficult to maintain/read.

Comment: that's a elegant solution and shrinks a lot of code, but doesn't solve it all.I think there ought to be a way to create a loop changing the numbers after the ids for a specific array element. Btw, thanks for assistance.

Comment: The question is still not totally clear to me. Can you provide an illustration or try to elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: I meant that I think it is possible to change the numbers that come after the IDs for an array. ie.:

Comment: var lin = [ id0,id1,id2,id3,id4];
var i = [0,1,2,3, 4,5];

for (i=0; i <= lin.length; i++){

 $(#id" + i, "#Div" + i,"#ico" +i).hover(function() {
            $("#Div" +i).css("display","block");
            },function() {
            $("#Div"+ i).css("display","none");
            });}